# Password recovery asp

Tags: html, sql, asp-classic

i am requesting a problem about forgot password .
if user forgot his/her password how can i return his/her same password in email address? My problem would be the SQL database password is encrypted how am I suppose to retrieve the same password instead encrypted.

i did like this:

```html
<!-- 
    METADATA 
    TYPE="typelib" 
    UUID="CD000000-8B95-11D1-82DB-00C04FB1625D"  
    NAME="CDO for Windows 2000 Library" 
--> 

    <%
    DIM strEmail
    strEmail = Request.Form("email")

    IF strEmail <> "" THEN
    
    %>
    
    <%
    DIM objDB, rs, rssql
    Set objDB = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    objDB.Open "Provider=MSDASQL.1;Password=langas;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=mmsg;Data Source=mmsg_web"
    rssql = "SELECT email_addr, medacist_password FROM medacist_user WHERE email_addr = '" & strEmail & "'"
    Set rs = objDB.Execute(rssql) 


    IF rs.EOF THEN
    Response.Write "That email address was not found in our database. Please click Back on your browser and enter the email address you registered with."
    ELSE
    DIM strPassword
    set strPassword = rs("medacist_password")
    

    Set cdoConfig = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")  
 
    With cdoConfig.Fields  
        .Item(cdoSendUsingMethod) = cdoSendUsingPort  
        .Item(cdoSMTPServer) = "10.1.1.186"  'Ongoing sever SMTP required \\'
  ''      .Item(cdoSMTPAuthenticate) = 1'
    ''    .Item(cdoSendUsername) ="<enter_username>"
    ' '   .Item(cdoSendPassword) ="<enter_password>"''
        .Update  
    End With 
 
    Set cdoMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")  

 
    With cdoMessage 
        Set .Configuration = cdoConfig 
        .From = "clu@medacist.com" 
        .To = strEmail 
        .Subject = "Forgotten Password" 
        .HTMLBody = "Here is your password: " & strPassword 
        .Importance = 1
        .Send 
    End With 
 
    Set cdoMessage = Nothing  
    Set cdoConfig = Nothing  


    Response.Write "Your password has been sent to your email address."
    END IF

    ELSE
    Response.Write "Please click Back on your browser and enter the email address you registered with."
    END IF
    %>

<!-- "Please click below link to reset your password: <br> <a href='https://www.medacist.com/login/test_globals.asp'>Click this link to reset your password</a>"  -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't supposed to retrieve the password.

You should generate a long, pesudo-random token. Store it for a short time (e.g. 24 hours). Send it to the user (normally embedded in a URL). When the user follows the link in the email, they should get a page allowing them to set a new password (and you can use the token in the URL to identify which user's password is being changed).

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Do you have a example of pesudo-random token code? I'm new to ASP and this seems to be hard.